# Data structure for storing huge number of indices, each pointing to a set

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures, dictionary

I am using a red black tree implementation in C++ (std::map), but currently, I see that my unsigned long long int indices get bigger and bigger, for larger experiment. I am going for 700,000,000 indices, and each index stores a std::set that contains a few more int elements (about 1-10). We got 128 GB RAM, but I see that we start to run short of it; in fact, if possible, I wanna go down even to 1,000,000,000 indices, if possible, in my experiment.

I gave this some thought, and was thinking about a forest of several maps put together. Basically, after a map hits a certain size threshold (or perhaps when bad_alloc starts to be thrown), save it to disk, clear it off the memory and then create another map and keep on doing until I got all indices. However, during the loading part, this will be very inefficient, as we can only hold one map in the RAM at a time. Worse, we need to check all maps for consistency.

So in this case, what are some of the data structure should I be looking for?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what the actual problem you are seeing is?

Comment: Can you explain more about how the data is used?  There are less flexible ways of storing the data that may work better, such as a sorted array, if they're suited to the problem.

Comment: The problem is I want near-native speed with huge amount of indices in the map. Right now, we have a memory shortage problem.

Comment: If you're on Windows, use ESENT (Extensible Storage Engine) instead.

Comment: Or at least use B-tree instead of your RB tree, and rely on OS-provided swap file mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, I think you have this:

```
typedef std::map<long long, std::set<int>> MyMap;
```

where the `map` is very big, and the individual sets are quite small. There are several sources of overhead here:

- the individual entries in the `map`, each of which is a separate allocation;
- the individual entries in the `set`s, ditto;
- the structures which describe each `set`, independent of their contents.

With standard library components, it's not possible to eliminate all of these overheads; the semantics of associative containers pretty well mandates the individual allocation of each entry, and the use of red-black trees requires the addition of several pointers to each entry (in theory, only two pointers are required, but efficient implementation of iterators is difficult without parent pointers.)

However, you can reduce the overhead without losing functionality by combining the `map` with the `set`s, using a datastructure like this:

```
typedef std::set<std::pair<long long, int>> MyMap;
```

You can still answer all the same queries, although a few of them are slightly less convenient. Remember that `std::pair`'s default comparator sorts in lexicographical order, so all of the elements with the same `first` value will be contiguous. So you can, for example, query whether a given index has any `int`s associated with it by using:

```
it = theMap.lower_bound(std::make_pair(index, INT_MIN));
if (it != theMap.end() && it->first == index) {
  // there is at least one int associated with index
}
```

The same call to `lower_bound` will give you a begin iterator for the int`s associate with the key, while a call to`upper_bound(std::make_pair(key, INT_MAX))` will give you the corresponding end iterator, so you can easily iterate over all the values associated with a given key.

That still might not be enough to store 700 million indices with associated sets of integers in 128GB unless the average set size is really small. The next step would have to be a b-tree of some form, which is not in the standard library. B-trees avoid the individual entry overhead by combining a number of entries into a single cluster; that should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I am combining your suggestion with Zaufi's suggestion (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14939735/144201) for B-Tree, and I see that I am at 492 million indices but I only used 10.9 GB RAM right now. My original implementation was at > 70 GB around these numbers of indices. Impressive.

Answer (score 2):

it looks like it is time to switch to B-trees (may be B+ or B*) -- this structure used in databases to manage indices. take a look [here](https://code.google.com/p/cpp-btree/) -- this is replacement for std-like associative containers w/ btree inside... but btrees can be used to keep indices in memory and on disk...

Comment: +1: I am performing an experiment with B-Tree to test your suggestion, and I see that it looks very promising. Memory usage goes down significantly.

Comment: the next step you may take is to use non-default allocators. try to play w/ smth better suitable for your data... take a look to `boost::pool` library and/or google for 'small objects allocator'

Answer (score 1):

For such a large scale dataset, you should really work with a proper [database server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_server) such as an **SQL server**. These servers are intended to work with cached large-scale datasets. An SQL server saves the data to a permenant cache such as a HDD, while maintaining good read/write performance by caching frequently accessed pages etc.

Comment: While database solution seems promising at first, we have performed experiment on it, and it seems after we hit about a million indices, the performance drops down to a crawl, and our C++ implementation beats it by several magnitudes. While the first several hundred thousand indices look fast & furious, after it hits a certain limit, the speed becomes slow & sluggish.

Comment: I'm doubtful that a savvy DBA couldn't optimize a database to your needs. It seems that your server has the potential for a huge amount of cache, so an "out of the box" DB would probably not be as efficient as one configured specifically to the job at hand. I'm not a DBA and so can't offer any real help here, but these platforms have been driving the industry for several decades now: millions of hours have been spent optimizing and fine-tuning their algorithms to squeeze out more performance. I'm really doubtful an "in-house" implementation could beat that performance

Comment: Perhaps those are commercial/industry level support (optimized right for the problem) for Windows side? We're on Linux side here.